# Where are MVC Controllers loaded when App is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know where the MVC controllers are loaded when the application is running. Server side or browser side?

Comment: What do you mean by loaded? The controller is executed on the server side

Comment: These may gives you idea https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mvc-architecture-its-pipeline4/ and https://opdhsblobprod04.blob.core.windows.net/contents/ed5efb1947c04bb29402a0c08d68958e/d0ed2e012c44fea6a368d4591ea14088?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=i9SdR6tM20dKWJ4bpJpqtVtAAulE0HjA0RUPmf9eFfg%3D&st=2020-01-17T06%3A44%3A58Z&se=2020-01-18T06%3A54%3A58Z&sp=r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC Controllers will be Server side.

View will be Client Side

Answer (score 1):

MVC  Controllers are Server-side.